# Prevent Duplicate Daily Report Emails being sent from Google App Engine

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, sendgrid

We have a problem. Our customers are complaining that they are getting duplicate emails in their in-box. Some days up to 5 or 6 instances of the exact same email at the exact same time. We don't understand why. The code has been re-written at least once but the problem persists.

I'll try to explain this... but it's a bit complicated :O(

Every night (early morning) we want to send our users a daily report containing usage stats. So we have a cron job:

```
<cron>
    <url>/redacted/report/url</url>
    <description>Send out daily reports to active subscribers</description>
    <schedule>every 2 hours</schedule>
</cron>
```

The cron job hits the servlet get method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    AccountFilter filter = AccountFilter.forWebSafeName(req.getParameter("filter"));
    createTasks(filter, null);
}
```

Which calls the createTasks method with a null cursor:

```
private void createTasks(AccountFilter accountFilter, String cursor) {
    try {
        PagedResults<Account> pagedAccounts = accountRepository.getAccounts(accountFilter.getFilter(), 50, cursor);
        createTaskBatch(pagedAccounts);

        // If there are still more results in cursor, then send cursor back to this servlet's doPost method so we don't hit the request time limit
        if (pagedAccounts.getCursor() != null) {
            getQueue(QUEUE_NAME).add(withUrl(WORKER_URL).param(CURSOR_KEY, pagedAccounts.getCursor()).param(FILTER_KEY, accountFilter.getWebSafeName()));
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Problem creating daily report task batch for filter " + accountFilter.getWebSafeName(), ex);
    }
}
```

which grabs 50 accounts and iterates over them creating new queued jobs for the emails that should be sent at this time. There is code to explcitely check the last report sent timestamp and update the timestamp BEFORE creating the new queued task. This should err on the side of not sending the report rather than sending duplicates:

```
private void createTaskBatch(PagedResults<Account> pagedAccounts) {
    // GAE datastore query might return duplicate results?!
    List<Account> list = pagedAccounts.getResults();
    Set<Account> noDuplicates = new HashSet<>(list);
    int dups = list.size() - noDuplicates.size();
    if ( dups > 0 ){
        logger.warning ("Accounts paged results contained " + dups + " duplicates!");
    }
    for (Account account : noDuplicates) {
        try {
            if (lastReportSentOver12HoursAgo(account)) {
                List<Parent> parents = parentRepository.getVerifiedParentsForAccount(account.getId());
                if (eitherParentSubscribed(parents)) {
                    List<AccountUser> users = accountUserRepository.listUsers(account.getId());
                    List<Device> devices = getUserDevices(account, users);
                    if (!devices.isEmpty()) {
                        DateTimeZone tz = getMostCommonTimezone(devices);
                        if ( null == tz ){
                            logger.warning("No timezone found for account: " + account.getId() );
                        }
                        else{
                            // Send early in the morning as the report contains the previous day's stats
                            if (now(tz).getHourOfDay() < 7) {
                                // mark sent now because queue might not be processed for a while
                                // and the next cursor set might contain some of the same accounts
                                accountRepository.markReportSent(account.getId(), now());
                                getQueue(QUEUE_NAME).add(withUrl(DailyReportServlet.WORKER_URL).param(DailyReportServlet.ACCOUNT_ID, account.getId()).param(DailyReportServlet.COMMON_TIMEZONE, tz.getID()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Problem creating daily report task for " + account.getId(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The servlet POST method takes care of handling the follow up pages of results via the cursor method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    AccountFilter accountFilter = AccountFilter.forWebSafeName(req.getParameter(FILTER_KEY));
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "doPost hit from task queue with filter " + accountFilter.getWebSafeName());
    String cursor = req.getParameter(CURSOR_KEY);
    createTasks(accountFilter, cursor);
}
```

There is another servlet that handles each report task and it just creates the email contents and calls send on the com.sendgrid.SendGrid class.

The eventual consistency in Datastore seems a likely candidate but that should be resolved within a few seconds and I don't see how that would account for both the number of customers complaining and the number of duplicates that some customers see.

Help! Any ideas? Are we being dumb somewhere?

**UPDATED**

For clarity... the email send task queue ends up in this method which does catch exceptions and reports them back to us. We don't see an exception for the duplicate cases:

```
private void sendReport(Account account, DateTimeZone tz) throws IOException, EntityNotFoundException {
    try {
            boolean sent = false;
            Map<String, Object> root = buildEmailData(account, tz);
            for (Parent parent : parentRepository.getVerifiedParentsForAccount(account.getId())) {
                if (parent.getEmailPreferences().isSubscribedReports()) {
                    emailBuilder.send(account, parent, root, "report", EmailSender.NOTIFICATION);
                    sent = true;
                }
            }
            if ( sent ){
                accountRepository.markReportSent(account.getId(), now());
            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String message = "Problem building report email for account " + account.getId();
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, message, ex);;
        new TeamNotificationEvent( message + " : exception: " + ex.getMessage()).fire();
        throw new IOException(message, ex);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2 AFTER ADDING EXTRA DEBUG LOGGING**

I see two POSTS in at the same time to the same task queue with the same cursor:

**09:35:08.397** 2015-04-30  200       0 B   3.78s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator
  0.1.0.2 - - [30/Apr/2015:01:35:08 -0700] "POST /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://screentimelabs.appspot.com/ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "screentimelabs.appspot.com" ms=3782 cpu_ms=662 queue_name=dailyReports task_name=8168414365365326983 instance=00c61b117c33a909790f0d1882657e04f40b2c7e app_engine_release=1.9.20
    09:35:04.618     com.screentime.service.taskqueue.reports.DailyReportTaskCreatorServlet createTasks: createTasks called for filter: ACTIVE with cursor: **E-ABAIICO2oQc35zY3JlZW50aW1lbGFic3InCxIHQWNjb3VudCIaamFybW8ua2Fya2thaW5lbkBnbWFpbC5jb20MiAIAFA**

**09:35:08.432** 2015-04-30  200       0 B   8.84s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator
  0.1.0.2 - - [30/Apr/2015:01:35:08 -0700] "POST /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://screentimelabs.appspot.com/ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "screentimelabs.appspot.com" ms=8837 cpu_ms=1348 queue_name=dailyReports task_name=50170612326424582061 instance=00c61b117c2bffe8de313e96fea8aeb813f4b20f app_engine_release=1.9.20 **trace_id=7e5c0348382e66cf4e2c6ba400529fb7**
    09:34:59.608     com.screentime.service.taskqueue.reports.DailyReportTaskCreatorServlet createTasks: createTasks called for filter: ACTIVE with cursor: **E-ABAIICO2oQc35zY3JlZW50aW1lbGFic3InCxIHQWNjb3VudCIaamFybW8ua2Fya2thaW5lbkBnbWFpbC5jb20MiAIAFA**

Searching for 1 particular account id I see these requests:

09:35:08.397 2015-04-30  200       0 B   3.78s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator

09:35:08.432 2015-04-30  200       0 B   8.84s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator

09:35:08.443 2015-04-30  200       0 B   6.73s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator

09:35:10.541 2015-04-30  200       0 B   4.03s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator

09:35:10.690 2015-04-30  200       0 B  11.09s /ws/notification/daily-report-task-creator

09:35:13.678 2015-04-30  200       0 B   862ms /ws/notification/daily-report-worker

09:35:13.829 2015-04-30  500       0 B   1.21s /ws/notification/daily-report-worker

09:35:14.677 2015-04-30  200       0 B   1.56s /ws/notification/daily-report-worker

09:35:14.961 2015-04-30  200       0 B   346ms /ws/notification/daily-report-worker

Some have repeated cursor values.

Comment: Add logging so next time it happens you know how it happened.

Comment: Easier said than done effectively - 10,000+ accounts and no easy way to detect when it is happening... if I could detect when it happens I could fix it :0)

Comment: Export your log to bigquery (trivial wth appengine) and find it there

Comment: Ah good to know - thanks will try streaming to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I will make a guess because i dont see the task queue code. Its likely that you are not handling errors correctly in the task queue. If a task queue finishes with an error, gae will re-queue it. thus if some emails were already sent, the task will still run again. you need a way to remember what you already processed in the task queue so a retry wont reprocess those.

Comment: Unless you think we need to catch Throwable as well as Exception?

Comment: I saw your update. 1) You are first sending the email then marking sent so a failure on between will send again, should probably be the other way. 2) i actually dont use java but i believe there is not way in java to catch "all" and instead you need to catch each possible exception.

Comment: So im curious now this is one of the few good questions ive seen these days. I dont see how it could be anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Zig! So... 1) We are actually marking the account as last sent before adding the Email send task to the queue. We are then also updating it to reflect the actual time sent after sending. 2) You can catch ALL in java with catch Throwable as all exceptions and errors inherit from Throwable. I have made that change just in case. Interesting update coming up!